# Where can I find binary packages for Apache Mesos?

Tags: ubuntu, mesos

I have been trying to install mesos on my VM. To be specific on Ubuntu Focal Fossa. However, I googled this and didn't saw any repository/binary packages for mesos. Can someone help me with this?

I visited the official site of mesos but I only got binary packages related to RPM based linux distros. Here is the link to official site: https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/

And I don't want to build the source release as it consumes time and at last generate errors which is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04: `sudo apt install Downloads/mesos_1.12.0-0.1.20220319122635_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eCI9xKAKdCyFa5HjrBt_jQeEFfAAqTZh/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for sharing this. How did you got this? Because I can see only source release in the official site and no binary release.

Comment: Built with "mesos-deb-packaging" https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-deb-packaging .... then repacked from `pkg.deb` to real package name  /  Ubuntu 20.04 conditions. ... One command tested: `$ mesos start-cluster.sh` ... so other testing is for you to do. E.g. do `$ mesos` to know options. ... Available v1.12.0 commands: `$ dpkg -L mesos | grep bin` ("admin commands" are at /usr/sbin/.)

Comment: http://rpm.pbone.net : Many other `mesos-1` packages, but all are for rpm based OS → Fedora, CentOS, OpenSuSe.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yeah definitely I will try the other commands.

Comment: @KnudLarsen One more question: Why they don't release binary packages for Apache Mesos on their official site? Approximately how much time did the build process take?

Comment: Mesos: Old application, building a package / maintaining the package for e.g. Debian/Ubuntu cost money. And anybody can build mesos, and add the few missing (empty) files. 2011 style i5: 4 hours → 2.7GB build space. ... Build-deps: `sudo apt install build-essential python3-dev python3-six python3-virtualenv libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev zlib1g-dev iputils-ping ruby ruby-dev python-dev autoconf automake git make libssl-dev libcurl3-nss libtool` .... `sudo gem install fpm`

Comment: @Knud The ASF covers the build costs of several projects. Money shouldn't be a problem for not distributing supported packaging

Comment: Worth pointing out that using Canoical Multipaas and/or microk8s, can more-or-less replace the need for Mesos on Ubuntu, and much more services support k8s nowadays than Mesos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent commit to the Mesos project, they've added unofficial builds to https://rpm.aventer.biz, where there is an Ubuntu directory

https://github.com/apache/mesos/commit/995c274bf5a3fb649622d85a771f3a22b4021650